# Ggplot does not label all interesting peptides for volcano plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bigdata

I have a dataframe containing 2479 peptides with their sequence, p-value and logfold change.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Sequence             p log2fold
  <chr>            <dbl>    <dbl>
1 FLENEDR          0.343    1.21 
2 DTEEEDFHVDQATTVK 0.270    0.771
3 DTEEEDFHVDQATTVK 0.112    1.18 
4 SCRASQSVSSSF     0.798    0.139
5 RLSCTTSGF        0.739    0.110
6 SCRASQSVSSSY     0.209    0.375
```

I'm trying to make a volcano plot while labelling the up and downregulated peptides. However, for some reason, ggplot only uses 6 labels. I have no idea why.

I have trying loads of different things. I tried using up and downregulation in expression column, I tried increasing and decreasing my cut-off values to check if this was a problem. I used ggrepel to try and center them out more. Nothing seems to be working. My latest tries with the code is in this code.

Basically as a last resort I made a new group and only took the significant and fold change peptides with me, resulting in 39 peptides. Then I used this as header and matched peptides between the two dataframes.

Another problem that arises is in my legend, a character appears since using geom_text_repel. I have no idea how or why this is happening.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyverse)

Volc <- R_volcano

expression <- ifelse(Volc$p < 0.05 & abs (Volc$log2fold) >=1, ifelse(Volc$log2fold>1, 'up', 'down'), 'stable')
Volc <- cbind(Volc, expression)

colnames(Volc)[1] <- 'Sequencenames'
Volc["group"] <- "NotSignificant"
Volc[which(Volc['p'] < 0.05 & abs(Volc['log2fold']) < 1 ),"group"] <- "Significant"
Volc[which(Volc['p'] > 0.05 & abs(Volc['log2fold']) > 1 ),"group"] <- "FoldChange"
Volc[which(Volc['p'] < 0.05 & abs(Volc['log2fold']) > 1 ),"group"] <- "Significant&FoldChange"
VolcFilter <- Volc %>% filter(group=="Significant&FoldChange")

p <- ggplot(data = Volc, aes(x = log2fold, y = -log10(p), colour=expression, label='Sequencenames')) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.4, size=2) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "grey","red"))+
  xlim(c(-4.5, 4.5)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=c(-1,1),lty=4,col="black",lwd=0.8) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1.301,lty=4,col="black",lwd=0.8) +
  geom_text_repel(data=head(VolcFilter), aes(label=Sequencenames))+
  labs(x="log2(fold change)",
       y="-log10 (p-value)",
       title="Differential expression")  +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        legend.position="right", 
        legend.title = element_blank())
  
p
```

[image]
[image]

Any help is much appreciated. Fairly new to R.

Comment: Maybe it's because you used `head(VolcFilter)` in your `geom_text_repel`. By default, `head` only shows the first 6 records.

Comment: I completely overlooked this. Thank you !!!